# Flock command deletes all the data when it is locking the file

Tags: bash, shell, process, locking, flock

## stop on errors

```
set -e

pidfile=/data/demo3.json

# lock it
exec 200>$pidfile
flock -n 200 || exit 1

# my code 
echo "hello"
sleep 20
echo "bi"
```

I am using this shell script(utility.sh) to lock demo3.json file. So, when this script(utility.sh) is running I want nobody to access demo3.json file. But this script is not working properly. Demo3.json file permissions are -rw-r--r--

at time = T1 From one terminal i am running this utility script
     ./utility.sh
     output - hello
at time = T1 From 2nd terminal I want to access demo3.json file
      cat demo3.json
but all the data inside this file gets deleted and i am also able to access this file at the same time. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: `exec 200>$pidfile` Here you're opening it for writing, which discards all the data in it. Use `exec 200<>$pidfile` instead

Comment: *I want nobody to access demo3.json file* File locking is advisory; you can't block off access to the file from processes that don't try to acquire a lock on it first.

Comment: So is there a way that I could use if i am running my script no other process can access demo3.json